# SVG inside slot not rendering in Chrome

Tags: svg, polymer, polymer-2.x, clipping, clip-path

I'm creating an element that clips images with svg and css. Because I can't pass an entire svg as a property I added it as a slot in the template.

It works in firefox but I don't get why it isn't working in Chrome.
I can see that the  element is being rendered as the last element inside the `#img-container` `div` on Chrome and on Firefox it is being rendered right below the `iron-image` element.

Please see this plunker example:https://embed.plnkr.co/mAtZQSTzxte1HuFFA8AB/

See the last example which displays the svg inside a slot.

Any ideas? Cheers!

Comment: It works in Firefox because Firefox doesn't support shadow DOM now hence doesn't has slots at all. So selector inside url works OK on Firefox but not on Chrome. I've tried selectors like url(::slotted(#swirl)) but unfortunately it doesn't help.